# AttributeError: 'JWTManager' object has no attribute 'token_in_blacklist_loader'

Tags: python, flask, jwt, flask-jwt-extended

I'm getting this weird error when adding the `flask-jwt-extended` decorator `token_in_blacklist_loader` in to my code. here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "home/app.py", line 42, in <module>
    @jwt.token_in_blacklist_loader
AttributeError: 'JWTManager' object has no attribute 'token_in_blacklist_loader'
```

here is my code:

```
@jwt.token_in_blacklist_loader
def check_if_token_is_revoked(decrypted_token):
    jti = decrypted_token['jti']
    token_in_redis = jwt_redis_blacklist.get(jti)
    return token_in_redis is not None
```

Thank you in advance for your valuable feedbacks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/v4_upgrade_guide/#blacklist-changes):

`token_in_blacklist_loader` has been renamed to `token_in_blocklist_loader`

You need to replace `@jwt.token_in_blacklist_loader` with `@jwt.token_in_blocklist_loader`